# pointer array when using scanf()

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf, pointer-arithmetic

In my code, I used pointer array like this.

```
arr = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            scanf("%d", (arr + i));
```

Because pointer arithmetic points address.

But I wonder if it's right to only write (arr+i) without * or &.

What is right?

Please help me.

Comment: What you have is correct. The `scanf` arg needs to be an `int *` which is exactly what you have. Using `*` would be wrong as that would give an `int` and using `&` would be wrong as that would give an `int **`.

Comment: For any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. From that follows that `&a[i]` is equal to `&*(a + i)` which is equal to `a + i`. Which is exactly what you have.

Answer (score 6):

The expression `arr + i` has the type `int *` and is equivalent to the expression `&arr[i]` (or even to the expression `&i[arr]` :)).

So you may write either

```
scanf( "%d", &arr[i] );
```

or

```
scanf( "%d", arr + i );
```